# Batch running composer update on multiple projects

Tags: wordpress, composer-php, batch-processing

Is there an easy way to batch run composer update on multiple projects with one command?

I'm using roots/bedrock for a load of WP installs and as their number increase it's becoming a drag to switch into each project to run composer update.

Answer (score 0):

If your on a *nix based machine don't mind using bash, then you can do some thing like:

```
DIRS="/path/to/project1 /path/to/project2 /path/to/project3 /path/to/project4";
for DIR in $DIRS; do cd $DIR composer update; done
```

It's dirty, but it works.